# How do you change the difficulty of the bots?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

With the standard configuration, Counterstrike: Global Offensive will populate the teams up to a maximum per team with bots to keep the teams balanced.

These bots are a quite easy, how can I make them more challenging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bot difficulty can be changed at the console and in the configuration files by changing the `bot_difficulty` variable, which can be set to one of the following values:

```
Easy:   0   bot_difficulty 0 
Normal: 1   bot_difficulty 1
Hard:   2   bot_difficulty 2
Expert: 3   bot_difficulty 3
```

There are also the following two commands which are supposed to re-scale bot difficulty depending on the average scores of the "human" players on the server;

```
bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low    defaults to -2
bot_autodifficulty_threshold_high   defaults to 0
```

`bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low` is the value used to determine that the bot needs to make itself harder, and `bot_autodifficulty_threshold_high` is the value used to determine that the bot needs to make itself easier. These values can be set to any number between 20.0 and -20.0 [but apparently this may be bugged](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2910029&page=2).