# Change Bot Difficulty In CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I just created a new game in CS:GO with no bots. Then used commands:

```
mp_limitteams 0 

mp_autoteambalace 0
```

then command:

```
bot_add_t X3
```

So now I can play alone against bots but those bots are harmless. I do not know how to change their difficulty. I already used command: *bot_difficulty 1* but it does not work. Can somebody tell me how to figure it out?

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this question as a duplicate of [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82064), but I'm holding off because you said that the `bot_difficulty 1` didn't work for you. How do you know it didn't work? Setting the difficulty to '1' sets it to "normal", which I think is the default. Have you tried `bot_difficulty 3`?

Comment: Look out for the names of the bots. They change when you set a different difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Ive found it works when I look at the bots and type the command seperately for each bot.